# Undefined CLR namespace Facebook.Client.Controls

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I followed the tutorial (http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/controls/login-ui-control/) but when I added the code to use the controls in the lib `xmlns:facebookControls="clr-namespace:Facebook.Client.Controls;assembly=Facebook.Client"`, visual studio accuses the following error:

```
Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace
'Facebook.Client.Controls' that is not included in the assembly.
```

I checked the references have been added, the rebuild already performed, closed and opened visual studio, etc..
I do not know what else to do! Can you help me find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your project, do you have any folder or class named  Facebook (created by you)? If yes, rename. Should be giving conflict. I think this solves.